# In Databricks, SQL uses spark?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have a notebook in databricks where I only have SQL queries, I want to know if it's better (talking about performance) to switch all of them to pyspark or if it would be the same.

In other words I want to know if databricks-sql uses spark-sql to execute the queries.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518878/does-databricks-translates-sql-queries-into-pyspark-in-a-python-notebook) question (looks pretty similar to mine), but the answer is not what I want to know.

Comment: The query syntax in `Databricks-sql`might slightly differ than `spark-sql`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely use PySpark in place of SQL.

The decision mostly depends on the type of data store. If your data is stored in database then SQL is the best option. If you are working with DataFrames, then PySpark is the good options as it gives you more flexibility and features with supported libraries.

It uses SparkSQL and DataFrame APIs.

Dataframe uses tungsten memory representation , catalyst optimizer used by SQL as well as DataFrame. **With Dataset API, you have more control on the actual execution plan than with SparkSQL.**

Refer [PySpark](https://databricks.com/glossary/pyspark) for more details and better understanding.